# Pagination when search and results are on the same page

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a `template` where the users pass a query and select a couple of checkboxes (these can range from 1-100). Then, my `view` does the following:

```
def search(request):
    results_list = search(request.GET.get("q", ""), request.GET.getlist("c"))

    # Pagination
    paginator = Paginator(results_list, 10)
    page = request.GET.get("page")
    results = paginator.get_page(page)

    return render(
        request,
        "web/search/show.html",
        {
            "query": query,
            "results": results,
        },
    )
```

The issue arrises because both the search and the presentation of the results happen on the same page. Therefore, when I want to include pagination, in my template, I have to do the following:

```
<div class="pagination">
    <div class="step-links">
        {% if results.has_previous %}
        <a href="?page={{ results.previous_page_number }}&{{request.GET.urlencode}}" class="prev-page-link">Previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        {% if results %}
        <span class="current">
            Page {{ results.number }} of {{ results.paginator.num_pages }}
        </span>
        {% endif %}

        {% if results.has_next %}
        <a href="?page={{ results.next_page_number }}&{{request.GET.urlencode}}" class="next-page-link">Next</a>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Please consider the usage of `request.GET.urlencode` because when the user wants to either go to the previous or next page the same `query` and `checkboxes` need to be passed. However, this creates a bug when the user goes past the second page, because the `?page=3&page=2` keep on piling up. Can someone point me in the right direction for solving this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution would be to repeat every GET parameter you need to handle in the link rather than use the full querystring, something like:

```
<a href="?page={{ results.next_page_number }}&q={{request.GET.q|urlencode}}&c={{request.GET.c|urlencode}}" class="next-page-link">Next</a>
```

A more elegant solution would be to create a Django template tag to build the URL based on the current state of the querystring, something like what is described in this article: [Dealing With QueryString Parameters](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/snippet/2016/08/22/dealing-with-querystring-parameters.html).

Comment: Hey @bug, thanks for the help (+1). However, this does not help me retrieve all checkboxes that have been selected, but only the first. Do you have any idea how to get the values from all checkboxes? Thanks!